# How does Camel pipeline work with jms endpoint

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am trying to understand the behaviour of Camel pipeline.
Below is the snippet of the route I am using to understand this:

```
from("direct:from").process(new Processor() {

                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {                        
                    exchange.getIn().setBody("Hello");                        
                }
            }).to("direct:one").to("mock:toThirdEndpoint");

            from("direct:one").setBody(constant("Second To Fourth Endpoint")).to("file://target/inbox");
```

The Body of the Exchange sent to "direct:one" is "Hello".
The Body of the Exchange sent to "mock:toThirdEndpoint" is "Second To Fourth Endpoint".
I want to know what would have been the behaviour had the first endpoint been a "jms:queue" endpoint instead of "direct:one".
What would have been the content of the exchange send to "mock:toThirdEndpoint"?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The to("jms:queue") in the middle of the first queue will act as other request/reply endpoints: the message "Hello" is sent as a JMS message, processed by the second route (down to "file://target/inbox"), and the result produced by the file endpoint is sent as JMS message to "replyTo" queue, which in turn is received in the first route by "mock:toThirdEndpoint"

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What if instead of file endpoint, I have a jmsqueue(e.g jms:queue:one) followed by another jmsqueue (eg jms:queue:two)..some sort of chaining of queues. Assume there is some processing between queue:one and queue:two. What gets sent to mock:toThirdEndpoint, output at the end of "queue:one" or at end of "queue:two".

Comment: The short answer: the response provided by jms:queue.two

Comment: The long answer: when using to("jms:queue") a message is sent to queue and the route waits for the response in the "replyTo" queue. When using from("jms:queue") a message is taken from the queue, processed, and then the result is sent in the "replyTo" queue. You can disable this request/reply behaviour with "disableReplyTo=true" endpoint option or turning the route or the JMS producer "InOnly"

More info: http://camel.apache.org/jms "About using Camel to send and receive messages and JMSReplyTo" and "Request-reply over JMS" paragraphs

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt and detailed answer. Unfortunately I can up vote your answer as I don't have enough reputation :(

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the original question comes from the definition of a pipeline and the exchange pattern applied on the endpoints participating in a pipeline.

- The pipeline pattern (http://camel.apache.org/pipes-and-filters.html) ensures that each stage should receive the output of the previous stage.
- The exchange pattern (http://camel.apache.org/exchange-pattern.html) defines how the route interacts with the different endpoints (channels).

Getting to the bottom line, if exchange pattern is not explicitly specified, by default Request Reply is used for direct endpoints and Event Message is used for endpoint using the JMS, SEDA and File components.

As a result of above patterns, the Event Message endpoints do not return any response so the pipeline proceeds with the input message of the previous stage. Consequently, the example below will ignore what the SEDA endpoint consumer returns. The Direct endpoint consumer with return an output message that will be forwarded to next stage of the pipeline.

```
from("direct:from").process(exchange -> exchange.getIn().setBody("Bob"))
    .to("direct:step1")
    .to("seda:step2")
    .log("${body}");

from("direct:step1").process(exchange -> exchange.getOut().setBody("Hi, "+exchange.getIn().getBody()));

from("seda:step2").process(exchange -> exchange.getOut().setBody(exchange.getIn().getBody()+"!"));
```

On the example, Direct and SEDA components were used for demonstration purposes, so direct depicts Request Reply pattern usage and SEDA Event Message usage. However, the default pattern can be specified on the route.